# How to use settings in azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension

Tags: azure, terraform

Trying to use azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "executor" {
  name                         = "example"
  virtual_machine_scale_set_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.executor.id
  publisher                    = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                         = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version         = "2.0"
  settings = jsonencode({
    "commandToExecute"  = "sudo yum update -y  "
    "commandToExecute1" = "sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk -y"
    "commandToExecute2" = "export IPZK=" + var.zk_ip
  })
}
```

Output is

```
  on modules/exec_scale_set/main.tf line 60, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "executor":
  60:     "commandToExecute2" = "export IPZK=" + var.zk_ip

Unsuitable value for left operand: a number is required.
```

How to pass variables to "commandToExecute2" = "export IPZK=" + var.zk_ip?

Answer (score 0):

"export DREMIO_IPZK=${var.zk_ip}" this is an answer